# Notation for intervals?

Tags: python

I want to make a Python class for intervals of real numbers. Syntax most closely related to mathematical notation would be `Interval([a, b))` or, even better, `Interval[a, b)` to construct the interval of all real `x` satisfying `a <= x < b`.

Is it possible to construct a class that would handle this syntax?

Comment: It's not, because python has it's own interpretation of brackets, you can try putting `[a, b)` in `str`

Comment: In practice, programmers will usually assume a half-open interval (closed on the left) unless you specify otherwise.  That's what `range()` does for integers, and it's how slice syntax is normally interpreted.  So the fully open, fully closed, or closed-on-the-right cases are the special cases that should have unusual syntax.

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible to "fix" syntactically invalid python by making a custom class.

I think the closest you can get to the mathematical interval notation in python is

```
Interval('[a, b)')
```

This way becomes even more lightweight if you are passing intervals as arguments to a function and the function converts it's arguments to an appropriate type before using them. Example:

```
def do_foo(interval, bar, baz):
    interval = Interval(interval)
    # do stuff

do_foo('[3,4)', 42, true)
```

[Possible implementation](http://ideone.com/BXBeXi):

```
import re

class Interval:
    def __init__(self, interval):
        """Initialize an Interval object from a string representation of an interval
           e.g: Interval('(3,4]')"""
        if isinstance(interval, Interval):
            self.begin, self.end = interval.begin, interval.end
            self.begin_included = interval.begin_included
            self.end_included = interval.end_included
            return
        number_re = '-?[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?'
        interval_re = ('^\s*'
                       +'(\[|\()'  # opeing brecket
                       + '\s*'
                       + '(' + number_re + ')'  # beginning of the interval
                       + '\s*,\s*'
                       + '(' + number_re + ')'  # end of the interval
                       + '\s*'
                       + '(\]|\))'  # closing brecket
                       + '\s*$'
                      )
        match = re.search(interval_re, interval)
        if match is None:
            raise ValueError('Got an incorrect string representation of an interval: {!r}'. format(interval))
        opening_brecket, begin, end, closing_brecket = match.groups()
        self.begin, self.end = float(begin), float(end)
        if self.begin >= self.end:
            raise ValueError("Interval's begin shoud be smaller than it's end")
        self.begin_included = opening_brecket == '['
        self.end_included = closing_brecket == ']'
        # It might have been batter to use number_re = '.*' and catch exeptions float() raises instead

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Interval({!r})'.format(str(self))

    def __str__(self):
        opening_breacket = '[' if self.begin_included else '('
        closing_breacket = ']' if self.end_included else ')'
        return '{}{}, {}{}'.format(opening_breacket, self.begin, self.end, closing_breacket)

    def __contains__(self, number):
        if self.begin < number < self.end:
            return True
        if number == self.begin:
            return self.begin_included
        if number == self.end:
            return self.end_included
```

Comment: @martineau Do you have an example?

Comment: What is the purpose of ":" in "-?[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make this exact syntax work.  But you *could* do something like this by overriding the relevant comparison methods:

```
a <= Interval() < b
```

This whole expression could then return a new `Interval` object that includes everything greater than or equal to a and strictly less than b.  `Interval()` by itself could be interpreted as the fully open interval from negative to positive infinity (i.e. the unbounded interval of all real numbers), and `Interval() < b` by itself could refer to an interval bounded from above but not from below.

NumPy uses a similar technique for array comparison operations (where A < B means "return an array of ones and zeros that correspond to whether or not each element of A is less than the respective element of B").

Comment: To me this solution seams about as syntactically clever and counter intuitive as `Interval[1](4)` and `Interval(1)[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change Python's existing syntax rules (without changing the whole language), but you can get usably close to what you want:

```
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, left_bracket, a, b, right_bracket):
        if len(left_bracket) !=1 or left_bracket not in '[(':
            raise ValueError(
                'Unknown left bracket character: {!r}'.format(left_bracket))
        if len(right_bracket) !=1 or right_bracket not in '])':
            raise ValueError(
                'Unknown right bracket character: {!r}'.format(right_bracket))

        if a < b:
            self.lower, self.upper = a, b
        else:
            self.lower, self.upper = b, a

        self.left_bracket, self.right_bracket = left_bracket, right_bracket

        if left_bracket == '[':
            if right_bracket == ']':
                self._contains = (
                    lambda self, val: self.lower <= val <= self.upper)
            else:
                self._contains = (
                    lambda self, val: self.lower <= val <  self.upper)
        else:
            if right_bracket == ']':
                self._contains = (
                    lambda self, val:  self.lower < val <= self.upper)
            else:
                self._contains = (
                    lambda self, val:  self.lower < val <  self.upper)

    __contains__ = lambda self, val: self._contains(self, val)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}{}, {}{}'.format(self.left_bracket, self.lower, self.upper,
                                   self.right_bracket)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r}, {}, {}, {!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                self.left_bracket, self.lower, self.upper, self.right_bracket)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interval1 = Interval('[', 1, 3, ']')  # closed interval
    interval2 = Interval('[', 1, 3, ')')  # half-open interval

    print('{} in {}? {}'.format(3, interval1,  3 in interval1))
    print('{} in {}? {}'.format(3, interval2,  3 in interval2))
```

Output:

```
3 in [1, 3]? True
3 in [1, 3)? False
```

Note: The `a` and `b` arguments can be any type that can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas [`Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) object.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_interval = pd.Interval(0.5, 1.5, closed="left")
print(my_interval)
```

Output:

```
[0.5, 1.5)
```