# Determine whether float is between two integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> value = "10.3445" # it starts as a string.
>>> value = float(value)
>>> value in range(10,20)
False
```

How can I determine whether float is in two integers? 
I am using python 3.8.1

Comment: btw, you shouldn't use `float` objects when testing for `in` for a `range` object. This will use the slow path, removing the constant-time `in` behavior for `int` objects and replacing it with a linear time search for non-int objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in range(10, 20)` is the same as `in [10, 11, 12, ... 19]`

You can instead do `10 <= value < 20`

Comment: hi, just for curiosity, is there a built-in function representing value from 10 to 20, including decimals?

Comment: There is not. `<` is the function `__lt__`, though

Comment: @Math In addition to what cricket said, there's also [`operator.lt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.lt)

Comment: @Math Also this is interesting: [Notation for intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39644748/4518341) - some folks created `Interval` classes that implement a `__contains__` method.