# If an input interval is within another interval, append to list

Tags: python, if-statement, time, append, multiple-conditions

I am writing a program that informs the user which animals will be awake and fed during their visit to the zoo, based on their inputs of day and time.
I have a class, a function that reads a file with info including name, hours awake, at what time they'll be fed, and some other stuff that all works.

```
 class Animal:
      def __init__(self, name, sleep, diet, awake, feed, number):
           self.name = name
           self.sleep = sleep
           self.diet = diet
           self.awake = awake
           self.feed = feed
           self.number = number
      def __repr__(self):
           return self.name + " " + self.sleep + " " + self.diet + " " + str(self.awake) + " " + str(self.feed) + " " + str(self.number)

 def readInfo():
      infile = open("zoo.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8")
      animals = []
      lines = infile.readlines()
      infile.close
      for line in lines:
           lineparts = line.split(" / ")
           name = lineparts[0]
           sleep = lineparts[1]
           diet = lineparts[2]
           awake = lineparts[3]
           feed = lineparts[4]
           number = lineparts[5]
           animals.append(Animal(name, sleep, diet, awake, feed, number))
      return animals

 def Awake(x):
      awakeanimals = x
      print("\nYou can see ")
      for object in awakeanimals:
           print(object)

 def Feed(x):
      matadjur = x
      print("\nand you can feed: ")
      for object in feedanimals:
           print(object)
```

Here is my code I'm struggling with:

```
def open():
     animals = readInfo()
     awake = list()
     feed = list()
     time = int(input("Enter a time interval, eg 07-16")).split("-")

     if 9 <= time <= 20:
          awakeanimals.append(animals[0].name)
     if 12 <= time <= 14:
          awakeanimals.append(animals[1].name)
     if 21 >= time >= 05:
          awakeanimals.append(animals[2].name)
     #same for the rest of the animals

     if time <= 12 <= time:
          feedanimals.append(animals[0].name)
     if time <= 13 <= time:
          feedanimals.append(animals[0].name)
     #same for the rest of the animals

Awake(awakeanimals)
Feed(feedanimals)
```

After that I have a simple menu which, based on the day the user inputs, calls the funciton `open()` and goes on to the time part.

I don't know how to get the correct input in the `if` conditions.

Also, the `time = input().split("-")` doesn't work due to `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`, so I'm thinking of using two time inputs, `time1 = input()`, and `time2 = input()`. However, that seems more complicated to incorporate in the `if` condition.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please try to provide minimal reproducible code with the errors.

Comment: Regarding your issue with the `split` function and integer conversion: `[int(t) for t in input("enter visit time: ").split("-")]` should give you a list of two integers describing the interval borders :-)

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't name your own functions the same as built-in ones like `open()` because it hides the original and is confusing to readers who know the language.

Comment: I would suggest creating an `Interval` class as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39646218/355230).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure about the if logic you want. Assuming its the check between a range, here are the things

The `split("-")` is failing because you are calling it on the intger value. `split` can be applied only on strings. And the **base 10** error occurs as `07-16` is not a valid number.

Here is an edited piece of code

```
def open():
    animals = readInfo()
    awake = list()
    feed = list()

    start_time, end_time = sorted(map(int, input("Enter a time interval, eg 07-16").split("-")))
    # time will be a tuple like (7, 16). We are sorting so that min value is first always


    if 9 <= start_time and end_time <= 20:
        awakeanimals.append(animals[0].name)
    if 12 <= start_time and end_time <= 14:
        awakeanimals.append(animals[1].name)
    if 21 >= start_time and end_time >= 05:
        awakeanimals.append(animals[2].name)
    # same for the rest of the animals

    if start_time <= 12 <= end_time:
        feedanimals.append(animals[0].name)
    if start_time <= 13 <= end_time:
        feedanimals.append(animals[0].name)
    # same for the rest of the animals
```

Which will work for the input issue and the comparisons mostly.